# How to providing a html form to store few text fields and few files (doc, pdf, image) in a row by clicking on submit button in mysql db with php?

Tags: php, html

I want store few text fields and few files by single click on submit and show them together in a rows of a table, like I have lots of book, so I want to store it in MySql db and retrieve in way something like:

---

[SOMETHING LIKE THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEpgC.png)

|  **BOOK NAME-**      |  **WRIER NAME**  ||   **COVER PAGE**    |  **BOOK PDF**||

|---------------------|-----------------------|---------------------|----------------------|

|         ......... PHP........        |...... C PAUL.....  .   .| view/download       | view/download|
|---------------------|----------------------|-------------------------|------------------|

|        .... HTML .........       |....       H PAUL........     .| view/download.....       |view/download|
|---------------------|----------------------|-------------------------|---------------------|

|         ......... MySql ....     | ......      U PAUL.....     .| view/download  ...     | view/download|
|---------------------|-----------------------|------------------------|----------------------|

1: How to store html form data as **Name, Writer** in **text** and other fields as **file(pdf, doc, word, excel)**, in different tables. Fot text I have a table **book_info** and for file path I have table **book_file_path**.
I will use MySql **JOIN** to retrieve rows from two tables and join them and present in a single table in HTML.

2: File should be stored in ftp server and I want to use the file path to display the view/download link in table. What is the way to implement this ?
Please help me, I want to learn. Searched a lot on various websites and tutorials but have not found a one to be understood easily.

3: I want to do this with PHP and MySql and HTML forms. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes it is all possible

Comment: Please tell me how to do this ?